# Php print double slash instead only 1

Tags: php, string

I read a string from config.ini 
the string is

```
config.ini
[section]
param = "#1234\y"
```

then when I read this code and print it in logs or try to send it to the server or socket this will print the following:

```
#1234\\y
```

How can I make sure I will send only one backslash

also when I get from config without \y . and try to concatenate that via php like $x.'\y' it is the same and not working.

it's working only if I define a variable with the string and not from the config

my udp server I need to send the string

```
    //Send the message to the server
    if( ! socket_sendto($sock, $newstr , strlen($newstr) , 0 , $ip , $port))
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        throw new Exception("Could not send data: $errorcode $errormsg \n");
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, just read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) about strings, it’s all there.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is wrongfully escaped **input** - not wrongfully escaped output.

either try `parse_ini_file ($filename, true, INI_SCANNER_RAW);` in order to disable parsing, which would lead to not to escaping the backslashes - or change the `INI` to `param = '#1234\y'`.

in case not able to fix the string input, here's how to fix the output string (the worst possible solution):

```
$newstr = str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $mystr);
```

or

```
$newstr = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '\\', $mystr);
```

Comment: i can't change the ini reading   . is there any option besides that ?

Comment: @Tuz `INI_SCANNER_RAW` might be the best option, because it disables the parsing, therefore also disables the escaping of backslashes; else you would have to manipulate the resulting array. the docs read: `$scanner_mode`  Can either be `INI_SCANNER_NORMAL` (default) or `INI_SCANNER_RAW`. If `INI_SCANNER_RAW` is supplied, then option values will not be parsed.`

Comment: @Tuz why you can't change the `INI` reading? you might probably read those values somewhere?

Comment: Because there are also lot of in I parans  and I can't make regression

Comment: @Tuz while no single one of those parameters would need to be parsed (and escaped), this would be no regression at all, but rather be the expected behavior of `parse_ini_file()`. "can't change that code because I'm afraid that something could break" is not really an argument... while able to revert to the previous revision at any time.

Comment: it is still print with // .  instaed /   (your preg_replace solution)

Comment: @Tuz you might manipulate the wrong string, or assign it to the wrong variable. simply fix the function which reads the `INI` and the problem would be properly fixed, instead of adding some questionable workaround... it seems you ignore my answer, in particular the first line of it.

Comment: done but it makes problem with others params like db connection string ..etc
is there any other option ?

Comment: also i talking about slash . and not backslash

Comment: and i tried it  in and it is not working . and sorry I meant slash and not backslash

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading from a config file you could also using single quotes around the value definition.

```
param = ‘#1234\y’
```

This will ensure the backslash is not escaped. For information check out [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).

If reading from reading from a script you could consume the var  using the `PHP` method, ‘stripslashes’.

`stripslashes($param)`

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php):

> Returns a string with backslashes stripped off. (\' becomes ' and so
>   on.) Double backslashes (\) are made into a single backslash ().

Comment: why you copy my answer? besides those quotation marks are obviously a syntax error.

Comment: I typed this on my iPhone. It’s hard not to reach the same conclusion if your right and haven’t seen an existing answer. The goal is to help the op. I would hope simple syntax errors on a 10 char bit of code could be overseen by the op.

Comment: It would help if you added anything about string parsing, e.g difference in PHP using single quotes/double quotes ;)

Comment: Those quotes are cancer.

Answer (score 0):

bydefault when you sending some data on server it will be encoded, to decrypt the data on other side you must use php urldecode() function as

```
echo urldecode("#1234\\y");// output:#1234\y
```

Comment: you need to write this other side where you are receiving the data

Comment: what do you mean  other side
I updated my server code

Comment: this is working  only with one slash .  , and this is the problem . how do I create only one slsh